# Remove an unknown part of a line using sed

Tags: sed

I want to go from:

[important text, numbers/letters only] [unknown text]/Windows/[text that I want to keep, will have slashes]

to

[important text, numbers/letters only] Windows/[text that I want to keep, will have slashes]

The unknown text could be a range of possibilities but it will not contain Windows

So basically I want to cut off the text before Windows that comes after  [important text, numbers/letters only]

The space after important text will always be the first space in the line

I also want it to be able to work if the unknown text and the slash after it are not present

Comment: If someone can figure out how to read everything to the right of Windows into a variable I think I will be able to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give any live examples so I'm assumming something like this is a valid example

```
abc123 unknown text which might have spaces/Windows/There might be /es here
```

My main assumption is that the first section doesn't have spaces. Otherwise You don't really have a way to deliniate between the important and the unknown text.

You can achieve what you are after with

```sh
sed -e 's/^\([^ ]\) [^/]*\/Windows/\1 Windows/'
```

The first set of parantheses captures everything from the start of the line that doesn't have a space in it. We then throw away everything up until '/Windows' and keep everything after that.

Comment: echo asdfsdfa23423 C:/Windows/fun | sed -e 's/^\([^ ]\) [^/]*\/Windows/\1 Windows/'

returns

asdfsdfa23423 C:/Windows/fun

Comment: sed -e 's/ [^/]*\/Windows/ Windows/'